# Getting the code to randomly choose one of x amount of choices

Tags: java, android

I used to program with a language where, if I wanted a number from a set of different numbers, I could go  x=choose(0,-1,2,5) and then it would randomly choose one of those options and give me a result. But since I've been working with Android and Java, I don't know a way to replicate that function as there's nothing I can find in the Android SDK that is like it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your numbers are placed in an integer array:

```
int[] numbers = {0, -1, 2, 5};
```

You can put a random number into x as:

```
int x = numbers[Random.nextInt(4)];
```

**EDIT:**

Probably creating a static function in a class would make this solution more like the one you used with your previous language:

```
public class MyUtil{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static int choose(int ... numbers){
        return numbers[random.nextInt(numbers.length)];
    }
}
```

You can use this function anywhere in your code as:

```
int x = MyUtil.choose(0, -1, 2, 5);
```

Comment: ooo i was just typing this..........:    x can also be equal to numbers[Math.Random()*3], i must have typed this.........  lol

Comment: ah that makes a little more sense and is only just a little bit more work

Comment: I guess what you trying to achieve is to abstract the random choice logic into a function. Check out my answer after "EDIT".

Comment: ah "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method nextInt(int) from the type Random" now what?

Answer (score 0):

Use the random function to generate an integer. That integer can be an index to a list of your options.

Comment: i was thinking that but its not very flexible as i'd have to have an index that was as big as how many options i wanted and would just become a mess the more i tried to fit in

Answer (score 0):

You can use the varargs feature:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

public static int choose(int ... numbers){
        return numbers[random.nextInt(numbers.length)];
}
```

This will make your code very similar to what you expect. The array creation is implicit:

```
int x = choose(1,5,20,4);
```